# how do I get only the date from the string "2022-05-25T15:48:50.000Z" using moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using moment.js library and for the example lets say I have the code -

`import moment from "moment-timezone";`

`const date = "2022-05-25T15:48:50.000Z"`

I've tried using `moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD")` but I am getting the previous date - 2022-05-24 as a result.

I know it has to do with utc, and my project has in it's setting the line 'moment.tz.setDefault("Etc/UTC")` which from my understand is supposed to fix it, but it doesn't.

I only need it to have the final result of 2022-05-25 and I know I am missing something really small here..

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: `console.log("2022-05-25T15:48:50.000Z".split('T')[0]);` --> using just javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this
`var newStringDate = yourDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10);`
or

```
var newStringDate = yourDate.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your format is ISO8601 format, you could check from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

You can try to send the full format to the function

```js
const date = "2022-05-25T15:48:50.000Z"
var now = moment.utc(date,"YYYY-MM-DD\THH:mm:ss\Z").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
document.getElementById('now').innerHTML = now;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.2.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<strong>Should Show: 2022-05-25</strong>
<div id="now"></div>
```